# How to replace unique value with True and other values with False in Tensor.tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Summary**

I am looking for a function `is_unique` that for each element in a tensorflow `tf.Tensor` returns a boolean value whether its value is unique within the tensor.

**Example input / output**:

```
In [7]: idx = tf.constant([162, 223, 276, 162, 261, 215,   0,   0,   0], dtype=tf.int64)
In [8]: is_unique(idx)
Out[8]: <tf.*Tensor*: shape=(9,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False])>
```

*Adding another example on request for a tensor with higher rank:* For a rank-2 tensor

```
tf.constant([[1, 2], [1, 3]], dtype=tf.int32)
```

the function would yield

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True]])>
```

This seems to be rather basic, but I believe there is no such function in tensorflow, or is there?

**My code**:

I haven't found a simple way to achieve this with `tf.unique` et al., so my current implementation looks like this:

```
def is_unique(t):
    return tf.equal(
        tf.reduce_sum(
            tf.cast(
                t[:,tf.newaxis] == t,
                tf.int64,
            ),
        axis = 1
        ),
        1
    )
```

(Basically, this creates a matrix of comparisons of every element with every other, counts the number of positive outcomes per row and compares this with 1.)

This won't work with tensors of rank > 1 and needs quadratic memory in the tensor size, so feel free to propose better solutions.

Comment: Well, for now I am happy with my implementation as I only need to check tensors of rank 1. But from a more global point of view, it would be nice to have a more general implementation :)

Comment: I added an example input / output for rank 2.

Comment: So you want element-wise uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, the idea being that I can always break down larger tensors into smaller and check uniqueness individually if needed? (May need to think about this further...)

Comment: You could use the built in [tf.unique_with_counts](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts)

Comment: I looked into that (it's the "et al." :D), but it seemed to be much more complicated. Please show me how if you have an easy solution with `unique_with_counts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tensorflow.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts) and [`tf.math.reduce_any`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_any)

For `rank==1`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([162, 223, 276, 162, 261, 215,   0,   0,   0], dtype=tf.int64)
y, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(x)
res = tf.reduce_any(x[:, None] == y[count < 2], axis=1)
print(res)
# tf.Tensor([False  True  True False  True  True False False False], shape=(9,), dtype=bool)
```

For `rank==2`:

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2], 
                 [1, 3],
                 [4, 3]], dtype=tf.int32) # 2 & 4 are unique

y, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.experimental.numpy.ravel(x))
res = tf.reduce_any(x[..., None] == y[count < 2], axis=2)
print(res)

# tf.Tensor(
# [[False  True]
#  [False False]
#  [ True False]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=bool)
```

For another Input:

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2], 
                 [1, 3], 
                 [3, 1]], dtype=tf.int32) # 2 is unique

y, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.experimental.numpy.ravel(x))
res = tf.reduce_any(x[..., None] == y[count < 2], axis=2)
print(res)

# tf.Tensor(
# [[False  True]
#  [False False]
#  [False False]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this syntax means? `x[..., None]`

Comment: @DavidH.J., Yes, Sure, this `x[..., None]` keep `first, second, ...` dimension and add one dimension to the end of array, You can check this example: `import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(2, 3); print(a[..., None].shape); b = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4); print(b[..., None].shape)`. In tensorflow works like numpy and adds one dimension to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Rank 1 solution, although very similar to yours:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([162, 223, 276, 162, 261, 215,   0,   0,   0], dtype=tf.int64)
y, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(x)
x = tf.reduce_all(tf.where(x == tf.gather(y, tf.where(count > 1)), False, True), axis=0)
```

```
tf.Tensor([False  True  True False  True  True False False False], shape=(9,), dtype=bool)
```

Rank 2 solution (see improved version @I'mahdi)

Comment: This is not working for this : `x = tf.constant([[1, 2], [1, 3], [3,1]], dtype=tf.int32) `

Comment: Good point, I'd like to rely on "pure" tensorflow (i.e. graph-mode compatible.) Apologies to l'mahdi: I haven't downvoted your answer, but haven't tested this thoroughly enough apparently before upvoting this either.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig, see my answer , This is pure tensorflow and work for all input when `rank == 2`

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig you can have numpy operations in graph with `tf.py_function` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia `tf.py_function` has many drawbacks: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function